# Why can we write lagrangian for gauge theory without the traces?

Tags: gauge-theory, lie-algebra, gauge-invariance, yang-mills, trace

I understand that trace is needed in order to preserve gauge invariance of the lagrangian equation by using the cycling property. But I fail to see why the following equation holds true:
$$-\frac{1}{2}Tr(F^{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu})=-\frac{1}{4}F^{a\mu\nu}F_{a\mu\nu}.$$
I also fail to understand how is the gauge symmetry preserved in the right term of this equation, I know that the $a$ index means that we are considering only the components and not the whole field but then I'm not even clear on how should I apply the field transformation such as an $SU(2)$ matrix to such components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply because
$$\text{tr } F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu} = \text{tr } F^{\mu\nu a} F_{\mu\nu}^b T_a T_b = F^{\mu\nu a} F_{\mu\nu}^b\, \text{tr } T_a T_b = \frac12 F^{\mu\nu a} F_{\mu\nu}^b \,  \delta_{ab} = \frac12 F^{\mu\nu a} F_{\mu\nu}^a$$
where the normalization $\text{tr}(T_aT_b) = \delta_{ab}/2$ is conventional.

Comment: What is $T_a$ ?

Comment: $T_a$ is one of the generator of the group (for example in SU(2) $T_a=\frac{\sigma_a}{2}$).
Thank you for your answer. In such a term then the gauge transformation simply gets "eaten up" by the trace and then is automatically gauge invariant?

Comment: @Ringo_00 I suppose you could put it that way, yeah!